# Exactly how do you derive Riemann's explicit formula correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I know the functional equation etc and I have seen a complete proof of von Mangoldt's version of the formula via a free paper online but I would like to read a direct proof.
You know, the formula that says

$$J(x)=li(x)-\sum\limits_{\rho} li(x^{\rho})-\log(2)+\int\limits_x^{\infty}\frac{1}{t(t^2-1)\log t}dt$$

Please give links that are free or at least free to read online or something like that.

Comment: Sorry for the WolframAlpha-like math syntax, I'm not used to the syntax used here.

Comment: This is not a research-level question, you'd better ask it on Math.SE.

Comment: it might also help if you explain a bit more what precisely you are looking for, for example with reference to [these notes](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/mfms_notes_02.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Lambda(n) = \log p$ if $n=p^k$ is a prime power, $\Lambda(n)=0$ otherwise. Then $$\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) n^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)) x^{-s-1}dx, \qquad \Re(s) > 1$$
Thus, by inverse Mellin/Laplace/Fourier transform
$$\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n) = \frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \frac{x^s}{s}ds, \qquad \Re(s) > 1$$
Then the Riemann [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)) follows by applying the residue theorem
$$\frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}+\int_{\sigma+iT}^{-\infty+iT}+\int_{-\infty+iT}^{-\infty-iT}+\int_{-\infty-iT}^{\sigma-iT} \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \frac{x^s}{s}ds $$
$$=\sum_\beta Res(\frac{-\zeta'(s)x^s}{\zeta(s)s},\beta) = x-\log2\pi -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{-2k}-\sum_{|\Im(\rho)|< T} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$$
And carefully letting $T \to \infty$,  using the density of zeros to show that $\int_{\sigma+iT}^{-\infty+iT}+\int_{-\infty+iT}^{-\infty-iT}+\int_{-\infty-iT}^{\sigma-iT} \frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \frac{x^s}{s}ds  \to 0$ and hence 
$$\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n) = x-\log2\pi -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{-2k}-\sum_{\rho} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$$

Finally the explicit formula for $J(x)= \sum_{n \le x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$ follows by differentiating, multiplying by $\frac{1_{x \ge 2}}{\log x}$ and integrating, transferring the formula for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ to $\log \zeta(s)$.

Comment: How do you "use the density of zeros" to show that whatever you're calculating is zero? I think -zeta'(s)/zeta(s) oscillates without bound as s-> -inf...

Comment: @JustSomeNerdyTeen Use the functional equation to show the only problematic term is $\int_{\sigma+iT}^{-1+iT}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{x^s}{s}ds$. With the density of zeros (which follows from the functional equation) show there is a sequence $t_n\to \infty $ such that $\frac{\zeta'(a+it_n)}{\zeta(a+it_n)} = o(t_n)$